# Flutter get all files and folders from storage

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-test

I am working on the app and for that, I need to get all files from storage it can be mp3,img pdf or anything. I followed a tutorial and they worked on flutter_file_manager. and this package is discontinued

Comment: take a look at the package `path_provider`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [file_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker) package instead. Moreover, you may need to use the [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) package along with the `file_picker` package. Complete documentation and examples can be found on the pub pages of the mentioned packages.

Here are some code samples:

To pick a single file:

```
FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles();

if (result != null) {
  File file = File(result.files.single.path);
} else {
  // User canceled the picker
}
```

To pick multiple files:

```
FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(allowMultiple: true);

if (result != null) {
  List<File> files = result.paths.map((path) => File(path)).toList();
} else {
  // User canceled the picker
}
```

To pick multiple files with Extensions filters:

```
FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
  type: FileType.custom,
  allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'pdf', 'doc'],
);
```

To pick a directory:

```
String? selectedDirectory = await FilePicker.platform.getDirectoryPath();

if (selectedDirectory == null) {
  // User canceled the picker
}
```

The usage for `path_provider` package:

```
Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
String tempPath = tempDir.path;

Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
String appDocPath = appDocDir.path;
```